# Django Admin URL reverse to admin users

Tags: django, django-admin

I would like to know How I can redirect admin users logged in my Django application (Django 2.0) to the user admin webpage ?

In my menu, I have :

```
<li><a target="_blank" href="{% url "admin:index" %}">Administration</a></li>
```

But How I could redirect to `/admin/auth/user` ?

I tried :

```
<a target="_blank" href="{% url "admin:auth:user" %}">Utilisateurs</a>
```

or

```
<a target="_blank" href="{% url opts|admin_urlname:'user' %}">Utilisateurs</a>
```

But I don't overcome to redirect to user admin page thanks to Django documentation ([Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls))

**EDIT :**

Thanks to Alasdair's answer, I have :

```
<ul class="sublist">
        <strong> Utilisateurs </strong>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="{% url "admin:auth_user_add" %}">Nouvel utilisateur</a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="{% url "admin:auth_user_changelist" %}">Liste utilisateurs</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="sublist">
        <strong> Groupes </strong>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="{% url "admin:auth_group_add" %}">Nouveau groupe</a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="{% url "admin:auth_group_changelist" %}">Liste groupes</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To link to the user changelist, you would use:

```
<a target="_blank" href="{% url "admin:auth_user_changelist" %}">Utilisateurs</a>
```

Note that this hardcodes the app name `auth` and model name `user`. The `admin_url` filter allows you to avoid hardcoding these:

```
{% load admin_urls %}
{% url opts|admin_urlname:'change' %}
```

However, for this to work, you need `opts` to be set in the template context, for example:

```
opts = {'app_label': 'auth', 'model_name': 'user'}
```

That means you might not find the `admin_urlname` filter useful outside of the admin views (which already add `opts` to the template context).

Comment: It works fine ! So I edited my question thanks to your answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
<a target="_blank" href="{% url "admin:auth_user_changelist" %}">Utilisateurs</a>
```

Comment: Are you sure `admin:auth_user_index` works? It doesn't seem to be documented.